# How to detect if a C filestream points to a file or a serial device?

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I'm working on a C application that evaluates data from a USB laser scanner, which acts as a serial device. For testing purpose, I'm also allowing test data to be read from a file, because it is not convenient to always have the scanner connected.

I open the file/device like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "a+b");
```

And depending on whether I want to read from a file or the device, I pass a file path or something like `/dev/cu.usbmodemfd121` (I'm on a Mac).

This works fine as long as I've previously initialized the laser scanner, but I'd rather have my application do that. In order to do that, though, I must first figure out if I'm reading from a file or the device. **How can I do that, given the `FILE *` returned by `fopen`?**

I've tried to use `fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END)` which I expected to fail for the scanner, since it's stream doesn't have an "end", but for some reasons `fseek` does not fail..

Comment: Obvious man says, "Can't you just check the filename and assume that you're talking to a device if the filename starts with `/dev`?"

Comment: Obvious man is very pragmatic, and while I like @cnicutars way better, since it is more generic, I would've upvoted Obvious Man's answer if he had posted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could get the file descriptor using `fileno` and then do a `fstat` on it. The `struct stat` it populates contains thinks like `st_mode` which shows the type of fd. I am guessing for your non-file device `S_ISCHR` will be true or at least `S_ISREG` will be false.

---

If you have control over it, don't do `fopen` at all. Use `open` directly to get the file descriptor and then use `fdopen` if you really want C streams.

Comment: What is the advantage of using `open` first followed by `fdopen` in comparison to using `fopen` first followed by `fileno` and `fstat`?

Comment: @x3ro I guess there's no huge advantage either way, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

@cnicutar's solution worked just fine. Here's what I ended up with, in case it helps somebody (error checking removed for clarity):

```
#include <fcntl.h> /* open syscall */
#include <sys/stat.h>

int fd = -1;
int status;
FILE *fp = NULL;
struct stat fd_stat;
bool serial_device = false;

fd = open("/foo/bar/baz", O_RDONLY);
fp = fdopen(fd, "rb");
status = fstat(fd, &fd_stat);

printf("S_ISCHR: %d\n", S_ISCHR(fd_stat.st_mode));
printf("S_ISREG %d\n", S_ISREG(fd_stat.st_mode));

if(!S_ISREG(fd_stat.st_mode)) {
    serial_device = true;
}
```